# Nutch, Solr/Lucene and hibernate integration

Tags: hibernate, solr, lucene, nutch, hibernate-search

Sorry for my English. I use Hibernate for work with the database. The database contains addresses of sites for indexing Nutch.

1) Need to Nutch received from the database the addresses of sites for indexing.

2) Then add the address of the indexed pages in the database and search text with `id` into Solr/Lucene.

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there a particular problem you're running into?  You may want to review [this section of the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I did not find in documentation of Nutch to have such opportunities.